# Set image in DOM from parameter in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to make a URL like: www.mysite.com?q=name

From there, it will place in HTML:

```
<p align="center"><img src="image/**name**.png" alt="Logo" /></p>
```

What would be the jQuery attributes to do this? I am still new to jQuery and trying to learn.

Answer (score 1):

assign a Id to your img element and do:

```
$('#image-id').attr('src', 'image/<name>.png');
```

Where you replace #image-id with the ID you assigned to your  element and  has to be extracted from the URL parameters

To extract the  from your Querystring you could use [this plugin](http://www.mathias-bank.de/jQuery/jquery.getUrlParam.js) (or - just look at the code and take what you need)

So the complete script would look like this:

```
$('#image-id').attr('src', 'image/' + $.getURLParam('name') + '.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign an id to your `img` to identify it:

```
<p align="center"><img id="logoImg" src="image/**name**.png" alt="Logo" /></p>
```

Then use a jQuery selector on this id to change the `src` attribute based on your URL parameter. The URL String is split on the q= text and the value taken from it.

```
$('#logoImg').attr('src', 'image/' + document.URL.split('q=')[1] +'.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to just use the plugin mentioned by tigraine, but if you want to parse it yourself, you can access the params via `window.location.search`